# How to make the iris eyes respond to light?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, objects

[image]

I did a tutorial on modeling a realistic eye:
https://youtu.be/n0r0UnaIK_Y

Unfortunately, I could not adjust the (iris). How to make the eyes of the iris respond to light so that it narrows?

Someone who knows and explains deserves great gratitude!

Comment: Hi. The language of the site is English. Please translate your question to English.

Comment: Hello, everybody. In one lesson, I repeated the Realistic Eye https://youtu.be/n0r0UnaIK_Y. Can't make the influence of the retina on the light? Who knows, tell me a lot of THANKS!

Comment: You should edit your question with the translation.

Comment: how to make the retina affect the light

Comment: how to make the retina act on the light so that it narrows

Comment: It might be hard to get an answer before asking the question. I am afraid in order for you to get a good answer the question needs to be formed in a clear and understandable English language first. You should also clearly define your goals, all relevant context of what you are doing and what fails.

Comment: Sorry, I can't Express my question correctly. Translate words in Google

Comment: I edited your question as well as I could. I hope I did not change the intended meaning. Note that you can edit it further using the edit link at the bottom of your question if any corrections are needed.

Comment: Can you post the .blend file to https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ so we can understand what part can be contracted?

Comment: Any one else looking to help, the Tutorial has a section called Part 6 Pupil Contract starting at 5:04 in the youtube video.

Comment: @MrZak I believe your edit introduces a mistake. Please see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retina#/media/File:Human_eye_cross-sectional_view_grayscale.png We should be talking about the pupil or the iris.

Comment: @MartinZ I was editing according to text of original question; I didn't take into acocunt physics of the eye. Anyone can edit further

Comment: @MrZak What was the reason to change it from the way I edited it then?

Comment: @MartinZ adding relevant tags. I decided suggested edit was more or less correct. As I already stated above I was considering orignal text. And from Russian "сетчатка" is "retina" - it is advised to edit according to author's idea, not change what they want to say. But then again - anyone can edit or rollback if suggested edit was wrong

Comment: So many problems with such a simple question... I guess we will have to wait for user63045 to clarify what he meant when talking about making retina narrower then.

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%BE%D0%BA#/media/File:Eye_dilate.gif

Comment: here is an example